# How to remove data selected by grouped day from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe needs to get cleaned from certain days.
The days to be removed are selected this way:

```
df['_datetime'] = df.index
exclude_holidays = df.groupby(df.index.floor('d'))._datetime.last()
exclude_holidays.loc[exclude_holidays.dt.hour < 14]
```

output exclude_holidays:

```
datetime
2020-12-24   2020-12-24 12:07:12
2021-01-18   2021-01-18 11:52:57
2021-02-15   2021-02-15 08:46:44
2021-05-31   2021-05-31 11:29:36
2021-07-05   2021-07-05 11:56:05
2021-09-06   2021-09-06 11:33:40
2021-11-25   2021-11-25 11:59:37
2021-11-26   2021-11-26 12:14:51
2022-01-17   2022-01-17 11:59:38
2022-02-21   2022-02-21 11:59:42
2022-05-30   2022-05-30 11:59:56
2022-06-20   2022-06-20 11:59:53
2022-07-04   2022-07-04 11:41:38
2022-09-05   2022-09-05 11:59:30
Name: _datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now, how can I remove these days from the dataframe?

I tried this:

```
df = df.drop(df.loc[df.index.normalize() ==  exclude_holidays].index, axis=0)
```

..throws this error:

```
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

with this attempt:

```
df = df.drop(df.loc[exclude_holidays].index, axis=0)
```

no error but the days are not getting removed

this is the dataframe:

```
                    Open    High    Low     Close
datetime                
2020-12-17 08:30:00 3686.00 3687.50 3686.00 3687.50
2020-12-17 08:30:03 3687.75 3689.00 3687.50 3689.00
2020-12-17 08:31:17 3689.25 3690.50 3689.00 3690.50
2020-12-17 08:32:36 3690.75 3689.00 3687.50 3687.50
2020-12-17 08:43:12 3687.25 3687.50 3686.00 3686.00
... ... ... ... ...
2022-11-11 14:57:30 3998.00 4001.25 3999.75 4001.25
2022-11-11 14:59:40 4001.50 3999.75 3998.25 3999.75
2022-11-11 14:59:59 4000.00 4001.25 3999.75 4001.25
2022-11-11 14:59:59 4001.50 4002.75 4001.25 4002.75
2022-11-11 15:00:09 4003.00 4001.25 3999.75 3999.75
```

How can I remove the days from the dataframe?

Comment: How does your original DF looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
exclude_holidays = exclude_holidays.index.values
df = df[~df.index.isin(exclude_holidays)]
```

Comment: gives me a `KeyError: 'datetime'`

Comment: I don't get an error anymore but the days are not removed from the dataframe

Comment: Strange. What does 'exclude_holidays.index.values' output?

Comment: the output is `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: You ran it after the code above. You need before. Alternatively, post the output for 'exclude_holidays'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249550/discussion-between-gtomer-and-stanvooz).